# Paramiko won't install with Pip

Tags: python, pip, paramiko

Trying to use `paramiko` and Python tells me it's not found, so I try to install with `sudo pip install paramiko` and get this awful error: http://pastebin.com/GFpgXB07

On OS X. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The system Python in OSX is used for various tasks by the operating system, so modifying its packages is generally a very bad idea. This error looks like the operating system preventing you from doing something potentially very harmful – in general, doing `sudo pip install` *anything* within your system Python is a bad idea, unless you know *exactly* what you're doing.

So how do you install and use a new package safely? Use [virtualenvs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). This lets you create an independent set of Python packages that you can modify and update as much as you like, without risk of breaking your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have permissions problem. I agree with jakevdp but in that case virtualenv is nut your solution. Try the install with --user option. Doc says (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/):

```
--user 
Install to the Python user install directory for your platform. Typically ~/.local/.
```

Moreover, if you take this habit you will be safe of not screwing your system with sudo.